# Не читается XML

Tags: c#, xml

Имеется XML файл следующего содержания:

```
<TOXT>
    <IMAGES razdel_id="1">
<IMAGE theme_number="1">
<PATH  img="/img/333.jpg"/>
</IMAGE>

<IMAGE theme_number="2">
<PATH  img="/img/333.jpg"/>
<PATH  img="/img/333.jpg"/>
<PATH  img="/img/333.jpg"/>
</IMAGE>
</IMAGES>

<IMAGES razdel_id="2">
<IMAGE theme_number="1">
<PATH  img="/img/333.jpg"/>
</IMAGE>

<IMAGE theme_number="2">
<PATH  img="/img/333.jpg"/>
</IMAGE>
</IMAGES>
</TOXT>
```

и есть код читающий его:

```
public void OpenImages(int razd_id, int theme_number)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml/imgxml.xml");

        foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
        {
            int razdel_id = Int32.Parse(el.Attribute("razdel_id").Value);
            if (razdel_id == razd_id)
            {
                foreach (XElement themes in el.Elements())
                {
                    int them_number = Int32.Parse(themes.Attribute("theme_number").Value);
                    if (theme_number == them_number)
                    {

                        foreach (XElement images in el.Elements())
                        {
                            string img_path = images.Attribute("img").Value.ToString();

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

вылетает на с сообщением "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
нашел где скрывалась эта пакость:

```
foreach (XElement themes in el.Elements())
                {
                    int them_number = Int32.Parse(themes.Attribute("theme_number").Value);
                    if (theme_number == them_number)...
```

вопрос - почему не считывается значение? есть другой XML похожей структуры - все читает замечательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в 3-м foreach, где Вы Elements() достаёте из **el** вместо **themes**

Comment: конкретную строку не пишет. искал в гугле, везде пишут что какая то переменная имеет значение Null, я поисследовал и нашел что int them_number = Null.

почему не знаю, выше XML тот который пытаюсь считать

Comment: them_number не может быть null вообще никогда, не ссылочный тип.

Исправил ответ, простая невнимательность всему виной.

Comment: каким образом проверить? если я знаю что он там 10000^10000% есть. выше полноценный XML приведен, я его считываю, но не получается и theme_number там есть.

Comment: Исправил ответ, не поленился скопипастить и отладить)